# My Entity won't cast to IEntityWithRelationships

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I am having trouble casting one of my entities to IEntityWithRelationsships. I am using a lot the method for getting context from an entity, and it's been working fine so far. I thought that entity need only to have one or more relationships defined in Model and that's it.

Here's little bit of my code:

```
public ActionResult Update(StavkaDokumentaVM stavka)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    StavkaDokumenta st = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<StavkaDokumenta>(stavka);

    db.StavkeDokumenta.Attach(st);
    db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(st, EntityState.Modified);                
    db.SaveChanges();

    IEntityWithRelationships test = st as IEntityWithRelationships; // I get NULL here

    st = db.StavkeDokumenta.Include("RelationEnd1").Include("RelationEnd2")
        .Where(sd => sd.IdStavkaDokumenta == st.IdStavkaDokumenta).Single();

    test = st as IEntityWithRelationships; // Also get NULL
}
}
```

Entity in question has like 10 relations defined, so it shouldn't be problem.

What is going on here? I am really baffled.

UPDATE:

This is what I just did:

```
db.LoadProperty(st, "DokumentStavke");
IEntityWithRelationships test = st.DokumentStavke as IEntityWithRelationships; // I get NON NULL value;
test = st as IEntityWithRelationships; // I still get NULL.
```

Is this the way things are supposed to be?

Comment: Are you using POCOs? They don't inherit from/implement anything by default.

Comment: No, 'StavkaDokumenta' is an entity from a model, and 'StavkaDokumentaVM' is a ViewModel that I made based on the latter one.

Comment: Yes, but how was that model created?

Comment: Using EDM Designer. I did extend this entity with few additional functions, but I don't think that changes anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POCO entity does not implement `IEntityWithRelationships`. What you are doing is a hack dependent on dynamic proxy. Dynamic proxy generated by EF implements that interface but to have dynamic proxy correctly created [you must pass all prerequisites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd468057%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Well, I thought that "StavkaDokumenta" that AutoMapper created for me would be regular entity, but clearly, I was wrong.
Anyway, I cant create Navigation properties in my ViewModel class, because I get circular reference error when serializing it to JSON. So, I guess I am stuck with "refreshing" entities from database, to get what I need. Thanks.